# Qt: Potential side-effects of Layout?

Tags: qt, pyside

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
layout = QHBoxLayout()
print issubclass(type(layout), QWidget)
# Layout is not a kind of QWidget

window = QWidget()
window.resize(500, 500)
window.show()
window.setLayout(layout)

butt = QPushButton("asdf", parent = None)
butt.resize(100, 100)
butt.show()
layout.addWidget(butt)

print butt.parent() 

app.exec_()
```

The parent object of `butt` is `window` in fact.
But I haven't set its parent to `window` explicitly.
Can I say that the Layout Object has some side effects which may
set the added widget's parent to the container that it applied to?

Comment: It's at least unusual to include the question as comment in a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

[Relevant part from the docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts):

> When you use a layout, you do not need to pass a parent when
>   constructing the child widgets. The layout will automatically reparent
>   the widgets (using QWidget::setParent()) so that they are children of
>   the widget on which the layout is installed.
>
> Note: Widgets in a layout are children of the widget on which the
>   layout is installed, not of the layout itself. Widgets can only have
>   other widgets as parent, not layouts.